# In Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, Swagger JSON and UI generated without content type when Results.Ok is used

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, minimal-apis

When you define API end points like following both are same in functionality,

```
        app.MapPost("/todoitems", async (FileModel file) =>
        {
            return file;
        });
        app.MapPost("/todoitemsnew", async (FileModel file) =>
        {
            return Results.Ok(file);
        });
```

Both APIs should generate same UI and JSON output, but the point with Results.Ok is generated as no return content end point.

When a return object is used then the generated UI is like this (when  **return file;** used)
[image]

When a Results.Ok is used the generated UI is like this (when  return **Results.Ok(file);** used)
[image]

JSON generated is also missing content type.

When a return object is used then the JSON is like this (when  **return file;** used)

```
"responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FileModel"
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

When a Results.Ok is used the JSON is like this (when  return **Results.Ok(file);** used)

```
"responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success"
          }
        }
```

This creates a problem when you use Nswag code generators. Not found any answer in the documentation

**Is it by design ? or Bug ? Not found information on the same in the documentation.**

Comment: Swagger analyzes response type to generate this info. This is as match as it can determine from type returned by `Results.Ok`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add explicitly the produced response in this case.

```
    app.MapPost("/todoitemsnew", async (FileModel file) =>
    {
        return Results.Ok(file);
    }).Produces(200,typeof(FileModel));
```

should give you expected result.